# PHP create new array by value

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have an array like this...

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [path] => Array
            (
                [0] => level_1
            )

        [name] => 'Computer'
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [path] => Array
            (
                [0] => level_1
                [1] => level_2
                [2] => level_3
            )

        [name] => 'Laptop'
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [path] => Array
            (
                [0] => level_1
                [1] => level_2
            )

        [name] => 'Smartphone'
    )
)
```

and I want to create an new array like this...

```
Array(
[level_1] => Array(
    [0] => 'Computer'
    [level_2] => Array(
        [0] => 'Smartphone',
        [level_3] => Array(
           [0] => 'Laptop'
        )
    )
 )
)
```

Is there a native PHP way to do this?
I'm not a PHP wizard, Thanks!

Comment: On which basis you want to show this name, I mean to say, I want to know logic on the basis of which we need to show this. If we just swap array[0] & array[3], what will be the output you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php

     $techArray = array( 
        "level_1" => array (
           "0" => "Computer",
           "level_2" => array (
             "0" => "SmartPhone",
                "level_3" => array(
                    "0" => "Laptop"
                    )
                )
            )
        );

     ?>
```

You can try this, it will work!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your tips.

level_1, level_2 and level_3 is a synonym for a path (parent / child).

an example:

```
['path'] => array ([0] => red[1] => blue[2] => yellow)
```

> what will be the output you expect?

an array in which the keys are formed from the values of the path array, like

```
array(
   ['red'] => array(
      [0] => 'computer'
      ['blue'] => array(
         [0] => 'smartphone',
         ['yellow'] => array(
            [0] => 'laptop'
         )
      )  
   )
```